# How to find the index of an edited textfield in a tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a UITableView, in which, each cell has UITextField embedded. I have an array of values that I want to change based on which UITextField gets edited. Currently, I am using the function:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            editedValue = textField.text!
        }
```

But what I want to do is set a generic string, and if a user changes the text in a UITextField, then I can index the string and change that specific value. Is there a way to find the tag of the cell containing the UITextField that was edited?

Answer (score 1):

in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, do this:

```
cell.yourTextField.tag = indexPath.row // so we are setting the tag of your textfield to indexPath.row, so that we can use this tag property to get the indexpath.
cell.yourTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

now in your view controller declare this function:

```
@objc func textChanged(textField: UITextField) { 
 let index = textField.tag 
 // this index is equal to the row of the textview
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get parent cell of your textField and then find IndexPath

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if let cell = textField.superview as? UITableViewCell {
            let indexpath = tableview.indexPath(for: cell)
            // indexpath.row -  row index, indexpath.section - section index
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First define a protocol/delegate in your UITableViewCell

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate: class {
    func getTextFeildData(cell: CustomCell, text: String)
}

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var delegate: CustomCellDelegate!

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        delegate.getTextFeildData(cell: self, text: textField.text ?? "")
    }
}
```

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath function set the delegate of the cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}
```

Then confirm the delegate method to ViewController:

```
extension ViewController: CustomCellDelegate {

    func getTextFeildData(cell: CustomCell, text: String) {

        guard let tappedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) else {return}

        print("Tapped IndexPath: \(tappedIndexPath)")
        print("Text Field data: \(text)")

        // update your model here
    }
}
```

Comment: Not Working, Do you have any other solution?